# Problem with redirecting to main page with apache and nestjs

Tags: apache, debian, nestjs

I'm looking for solution for my issue, because I've tried everything that comes to my head and I'm still not able to solve it.

So, I have backend written with nestjs and on my local machine everything works as expected.

But when I run it on server and type just host name ex. https://example.com it shows empty page.
It is confusing because every other route works well except main one.

So I'm assuming there's something wrong on my apache virtual host configuration but I'm quite new to it and I don't know where the problem is.

My apache2 conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.com.ca-bundle.crt

        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia full
        <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        <Location "/">
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:50000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:50000/
        </Location>

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html/>
            Allowoverride all 
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
```

My nestjs app starts on port 50000.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
Error was caused by useStaticAssets() function. When I removed it, everything starts working properly.
To be able to still serve static files I changed it to nest's ServeStaticModule.

Cheers.